# Auto generate excerpt from ACF field on a CPT that does not support excerpt or content

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, child-theme, excerpt, the-content

I have a CPT which contains only 4 wysiwyg fields created with ACF. The CPT does not support standard WP excerpt or content fields.

I would like the CPT to generate an excerpt automatically from one of the ACF fields. 
I am not building a custom template to output it from, so I am just trying to filter `get_the_excerpt` whenever that is called within my theme. I want my custom excerpt to output on the themes index/archive pages or the default WP index page.

I have got to the point that it works **IF** I include support for excerpt in the CPT **AND** there is something in the excerpt field... but it does not work if there is nothing in the excerpt field.

I have seen and read a dozen or more examples of how to do this when outputting the result on a custom template, but found none describing how to achieve this automatically for a specified CPT using default templates.

This is what I have done so far:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'tvw_vv_excerpt_filter');

function tvw_vv_excerpt_filter( $excerpt, $post = null ){
  if ( $post ) {
    $ID = $post->ID;
  } else {
    $ID = get_the_ID();
  }

  $type = get_post_type($ID);
  if ($type == "village_vibes") {
    $text = get_field('ceo_message',$ID);
    if ( '' != $text ) {
        $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
        $excerpt_length = 20;
        $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '[...]');
        $text = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );

        $excerpt = $text;
    }
}

  return $excerpt;
};
```

I also tried to filter `the_content` as it looks like it tries to get generate the excerpt from that if one does not exist in the excerpt field, however I cannot get it to return my custom field content. I assume this is because my CPT does not have "editor" support.. 
This is what I did to filter the `the_content`

```
function village_vibes_default_content($content) {
    global $post;

        if ($post->post_type == 'village_vibes') {
            $text = get_field('ceo_message');
            $content .= $text; 
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'village_vibes_default_content', 0);
```

Question: Is it possible to make this work WITHOUT having the content field/editor support in the CPT?

FYI - I am using Divi with a child theme.

Comment: Is my question not clear? Happy to update it following any questions.

Comment: Ok, then. I guess I'm on my own here...